What is the most energy efficient transfer mechanism for ion acceleration?
This question asks what is the most efficient way of accelerating ions, however, the answer focuses on the following:

For the sake of argument, I am going to assume you are asking about
which mechanism can generate the highest energy particles.

So I'm more interested on the mechanism that has the most energy efficient transfer for ion acceleration.

A voltage across an insulating gap… works for Cockroft-Walton, Van de Graaff, cyclotrons, etc.

Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/618003/59023
